# Изменение размеров экрана двойным свайпом на android

Tags: c#, android, unity3d, unity3d-android, scale

Я хочу, чтобы размер изображенных на экране объектов, менялся при двойном свайпе. Под двойным свайпом я имею ввиду движение одним пальцем, например, влево, а другим вправо, тогда изображение должно уменьшаться.

Само уменьшение и увеличение я, конечно, реализую, а вот вызвать его надо при этом двойном свайпе.

**У меня есть такая идея**:

1. В Update проверяем тачи
2. Если имеем 2 тача, то просчитываем направление движения.
3. Если движение происходит в противоположные стороны,

   - Если друг на друга - уменьшаем
   - Друг от друга - увеличиваем.

Но что, если будет 3 тача, и правильно ли вообще так делать? Может есть какой-то простой вариант? В Интернете о запросам `изменение размеров свайпом`, `scale swipe` и тому подобное я не нашел вариантов...

UPD1: Нашел вот такую картинку того, что я хочу: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Возможно, можно что-то нагуглить по запросу pinch и unpinch. Если что-то найду, опубликую ответ и отформатирую вопрос.

Comment: не знаю как ты не нашел, вот первые ссылки по запросу "unity double click" и "unity swipe direction" [double click](https://forum.unity.com/threads/detect-double-click-on-something-what-is-the-best-way.476759/) [swipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41491765/detect-swipe-gesture-direction).

Comment: ну и вместо свайпа ты вызываешь метод `OnDrag()` и там проверяешь с позицией дабл клика, больше меньше и т.д. Ставишь ограничения по x, что например не может у тебя скейл быть больше в несколько раз и просто присваиваешь |разница_по_X| твоему скейлу, например

Comment: @Methorn Вы меня, возможно, неправильно поняли. Double click и ссылка не него рассказывают об обработке именно дабл-клика, т.е. клик-клик. А вторая ссылка - это обработка обычного свайпа и его направления: вверх, вниз, влево, вправо. А я имел ввиду, как это часто бывает в играх (обычно 3D), я смахиваю двумя пальцами по направлению друг к другу и камера как бы отдаляется, смахиваю ими друг от друга и камера как бы приближается к объектам. У меня игра 2D, но это не важно, т.к. я реализовал само "приближение". Мне нужно понять, как отлавливать подобное движение пальцев/ Добавил картинку :)

Comment: Извиняюсь. Действительно не понял сразу. Вот держи свое [решение](https://pressstart.vip/tutorials/2018/07/12/44/pan--zoom.html)

Comment: @Methorn Благодарю. Еще нашел подобное решение, если кому в будущем пригодится: https://kylewbanks.com/blog/unity3d-panning-and-pinch-to-zoom-camera-with-touch-and-mouse-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как-то так

```
[DisallowMultipleComponent]

public class Scaler : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Transform _scaleObject;
    private float _baseScale;
    private float _baseDistance;

    private void Update () {
        if (Input.touches.Length == 2) {
            switch (Input.touches[1].phase) {
                case TouchPhase.Began:
                    _baseScale = _scaleObject.localScale.x;
                    _baseDistance = Vector2.Distance(Input.touches[0].position, Input.touches[1].position);
                    break;
                case TouchPhase.Moved:
                    float CurrentDistance = Vector2.Distance(Input.touches[0].position, Input.touches[1].position);
                    float Rate = CurrentDistance/_baseDistance; // или на оборот
                    float Scale = _baseScale*Rate;
                    _scaleObject.localScale = new Vector3(Scale, Scale, Scale);
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```